# Devise gem - unclear "how-to" guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This post is refers to the following how-to guide in the Devise wiki: Require admin to activate account before sign_in

([link to how-to guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in))

I have already set up Devise authentication for my app without any problems, and everything works perfectly.

However, as the app is for internal use only, I'd like to require admin to activate new accounts before sign_in.

I have thus been trying to follow the step-by-step instructions set out in the "how to" article, but have come across some issues that I'd like to have clarified:

**1) Model Changes:**

**Under Model changes one is asked to:**

"Then, override the following methods in your model (User.rb):"

```
def active_for_authentication? 
    super && approved? 
end 

def inactive_message 
    if !approved? 
      :not_approved 
    else 
      super # Use whatever other message 
    end 
end
```

-> My confusion here arrives from the use of the word "Override". Should I simply add it to the model/user.rb file? No other changes required.

**The following step asks you to:**

"You will need to create an entry for :not_approved and :signed_up_but_not_approved in the i18n file, located at config/locales/devise.##.yml:"

```
devise:
    registrations:
      user:
        signed_up_but_not_approved: 'You have signed up successfully but your account has not been approved by your administrator yet'
failure:
    not_approved: 'Your account has not been approved by your administrator yet.'
```

-> My question here is about how to add them to the yml file correctly. Do I integrate it into the existing code (i.e., add user:... under the exsisting registrations:) , or simply add it to the top - including "devise:"?

**2) Controllers and views**

**The first part asks one to do the following:**

"You'll want to create a controller method that is admin-accessible only, that lists the unapproved users and provides a simple way to approve them."

-> My question is which controller are we talking about? Devise does not create an editable controller... do i generate one called user_controller or will this clash with the controllers in devise?

-> ...and in that case, do should it inherit from the devise controller?

-> Alternatively,  can I add the code to another controller entirely that I then use to access the new method? Don't like doing this as it would mess up one of my existing controllers...

-> a index.html.haml is also mentioned where one is to add code to display info from the user model. Can this page (my version would be a html.erb) be anywhere that you want to display the user status info, as long as it can access the new user controller method?

**3) Email Notifications**

-> everything seems pretty clear... is there anything here that I should take into consideration in terms of the email address used? When setting up devise I added my gmail address as a temporary measure. Will this complicate things?

**4) Reset password instructions**

-> everything seems pretty clear... add to:
app/models/user.rb

-> comment: seems like an awful lot is added to the user.rb model.?

Thats quite a list, but if anyone can help me I promise to create and publish a more user-friendly version of the guide... one that any newbie should be able to use succesfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Yes, you are just going to add those 2 methods to your resource model.

It's overriding the methods not because you should have them in your model but because they are in the gem already.

## 2. Yes you need a controller that you create.

You are correct, Devise not have a built-in template for you to manage users.  So yes, you'll have to create one on your own, or as you mentioned, add it to an existing controller.  For example, you could have an admin namespace, which has several controllers, including one for users to help you manage this.

```
#routes.rb

namespace :admin do
  get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'  ## just an example to show a dashboard in your admin namespace
  get 'manage-users', to 'users#index'
end
```

---

```
#controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
  layout 'dashboard' #custom layout for admins
  before_action :authenticate_user! #make sure they are logged in
  before_action :verify_admin #make sure they are an admin

    def index
      if params[:unapproved]
        @users.unapproved
      else
        @users = User.all
      end
    end

    private

    def verify_admin
      unless current_user.admin? # this implies that you have a method in user called admin? that checks for the admin role 
        flash.now[:warning] = "You do not have permission to be here.  If you feel this is an error please request permission from your administrator"
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

---

because the action is users#index, then the page would be views/admin/users/index.html.erb

However - I find that for admin tasks like moderating users, I have more requests to put it directly into the dashboard controller.  And I just do

```
@unapproved_users = User.unapproved
```

inside the dashboard#index action and add a widget on the dashboard with a list of any unapproved users

---

Then a quick scope inside of the user model to get the unapproved users

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,   :omniauthable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable , :validatable , :confirmable

  scope :unapproved, -> { where(approved: false) } 
  # this works because if you followed the wiki you should have a migration that has a default of false and doesn't allow nil, so every record will either be true or false for approved

end
```

---

This way, in your view, regardless of where you put it you can have an area with a user list each user with a checkbox that makes an ajax update request to that record approving the user.  e.g.

```
# views/admin/dashboard/index.html.erb or views/admin/users/index.html.erb or views/users/ .. etc, you get the idea, just make sure when it comes to managing users it's in a locked down place.

<table class="table table-striped" id="manage-users">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%- @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr id="user-<%= user.id %>">
        <td>
          <%= user.first_name %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= user.last_name %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= user.email %>
        </td>
        <td class="status">
          <%= user.approved ? "Approved" : check_box_tag('approved', true, false) %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then some coffee to catch the update

```
# javascripts/admin.coffee

->
  $('table#manage-users input[name=approved]').on 'change', ->
    uid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id').replace(/user-/i, '')
    $.ajax
      type: 'PUT'
      dataType: 'json'
      url: '/admin/users/' + uid
      data: user: approved: true
      success: (data) ->
        user = 'user-' + uid
        $('tr#' + user).find('td.status').html 'Approved'
        return
    return
  return
```

For the most part you you don't need a users controller when you're dealing with devise as it handles that for you.  But having a users controller in admin is an easy way to block access for non admin users and still allow the management.  Plus it's restful.

## 3 Gmail is just fine.

It doesn't matter what email address you use.  As long as you've set up your email correctly so that the activemailer can send, you're fine.

## 4 Relevancy is pretty much everything here.

The modern (as of now) thinking is that if it's related to the finding / validating / persisting of data, then it can go in the model, and if its scrubby complicated business logic, it should probably instead be a service object.